# How do I profile code beyond per-function level?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, profiling

AFAIK profilers can only tell how much time is spent in each function. But since C++ compilers tend to inline code aggressively and also some functions are not that short it's often useful to know more details - how much time each construct consumes.

How can this be achieved except restructuring code into smaller functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a **sampling profiler** (e.g. [Zoom](http://rotateright.com) or [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/shark_optimize.html)), rather than an **instrumented profiler** (e.g. gprof) then you can get much finer grained profiles, down to the statement and instruction level.

Comment: ++ Try Zoom, or any profiler that gets **stack** samples, at random **wall-clock** times, in the **interval you care about**, and tells you **per line of code** the **percent of samples it appears on**. [Here's a list of reasons why.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343) It's amazing how many profilers don't "get it".

Comment: @sharptooth: What makes line-percenting wall-time stack-samplers so effective is that they automate what is (IMHO) an even more effective [manual method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024) - random pausing.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) then you can get a summary of which methods are taking most of the processing time. Then you can use [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to view the results. It gives a very nice graph, through which you can easily browse and find bottlenecks.